# Multibyte to unicode wrapper c++

Tags: c++, windows, unicode, linker, multibyte

I am trying to link against libAR and running into **error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol** error in Visual Studio 2012 for symbol *arParamLoad*.

This particular code works with other programs I've written and after a bit of toying around I've realized that it's possibly a Multibyte/Unicode issue with the character set.

The current application that is trying to link against libAR is a non-console windows application which is using Multibyte approach to avoid the mess with string prepping everytime w32 api is called.
LibAR libs are compiled with Unicode char sets.

So what would be a good approach for calling unicode API from within multibyte domains.

How would I wrap these calls?

Comment: "Multibyte approach to avoid the mess with string prepping everytime w32 api is called" is incorrect, meaningless

Comment: Well I suppose they didn't want to do the conversion between mbs and wcs for every call. Nevertheless, I am in a pickle. There is a program in multibyte and a library in Unicode. Any recommendation on how to wrap calls made to the unicode library from the program?

Comment: I would change the app to Unicode.